# How does LINQ expression syntax work with Include() for eager loading

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

I have a query below, but I want to perform an Include() to eager load properties.  Actions has a navigation property, User (Action.User)

1) My basic query:

```
from a in Actions
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
select a
```

2) First attempt:

```
from a in Actions.Include("User")
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
select a
```

But Action.User is **not** populated.

3) Try to eager load 'User' into the navigation property in action outside of query:

```
(from a in Actions
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId    
select a).Include("User")
```

In LINQPad trying Include's I get an error:

'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

I think this is because LINQ doesn't support Include().

So I tried in VS; query 2 runs, but returns unpopulated User property.
Query 3 the extension method does not seem to exist, although it does exist on Action itself without the query.

Comment: The Action-Model has a propertie named "User" ? Do you have a DbContext ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks for the suggestions anyway.
The solution is to do this (2nd attempt in my question):

```
var qry = (from a in Actions
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId    
select a).Include("User")
```

The reason intellisense didn't show Include after the query was because I needed the following using:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Everything worked fine doing this.

Comment: The join will happen automatically, assuming your entity is mapped correctly in the context. You can achieve the same with a simpler query: `var qry = from a in Actions.Include("User") select a` If you are joining entities that are not mapped explicitly as Navigation properties (ie: Action does not have a User property, or that is for some reason not mapped as a Navigation property), then you would need the join, remove the Include, and you can then use `select new { Action = a, User = u }` to have EF return the joined data. (The latter is generally referred to as a Projection)

Answer (score 25):

Better, refactor friendly code (EF6)

```
using System.Data.Entity;
[...]
var x = (from cart in context.ShoppingCarts
         where table.id == 123
         select cart).Include(t => t.CartItems);
```

or

```
var x = from cart in context.ShoppingCarts.Include(nameof(ShoppingCart.CartItems))
        where table.id == 123
        select cart;
```

---

**Update 3/31/2017**

You can also use include in lambda syntax for either method:

```
var x = from cart in context.ShoppingCarts.Include(p => p.ShoppingCart.CartItems))
        where table.id == 123
        select cart;
```

Comment: Thanks for the `nameof()`. I keep seeing hardcoded strings of table names.

Comment: Of all the features they added in C#6, nameof has been the one I've used more than any other! Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 17):

If what you want is a query that will return all `Action` entities whose associated `User` entity actually exists via the `Action.UserId` [foreign key property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee794150.aspx), this will do it:

```
var results = context.Actions
    .Include("User")
    .Where(action =>
        context.Users.Any(user =>
            user.UserId == action.UserId));
```

However **you don't have to use foreign key properties in order to do filtering**, since you also have [navigation properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx). So your query can be simplified by filtering on the `Action.User` navigation property instead, like in this example:

```
var results = context.Actions
    .Include("User")
    .Where(action => action.User != null);
```

If your model states that the `Action.User` property can never be null (i.e. the `Action.UserId` foreign key is not nullable in the database) and what you want is actually all `Action` entities with their associated `Users`, then the query becomes even simpler

```
var results = context.Actions.Include("User");
```

Comment: Hi, your examples all show chained methods, my query is in Expression syntax as I showed above (using from/select). Can you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the basic query mentioned in your posted question you won't be able to see the User properties unless you return an anonymous type as following:

```
from a in Actions
join u in Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
select new
{
   actionUserId = a.UserId
   .
   .
   .
   userProperty1 = u.UserId
};
```

However to use the Include method on the ObjectContext you could use the following:

Make sure you have LazyLoading off by using the following line:

```
entities.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Then proceed by

```
var bar = entities.Actions.Include("User");
var foo = (from a in bar
           select a);
```

Comment: From my understanding, `Include("User")` is meant to trigger eager loading, so to turn off lazy loading with `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` is at best redundant but ultimately mislead. I think if you were to swap your 'foo' and 'bar' then the Include would work on the EF query and eager load the additional table.

Answer (score 0):

I use for this the LoadWith option

```
var dataOptions = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
dataOptions.LoadWith<Action>(ac => as.User);
ctx.LoadOptions = dataOptions;
```

Thats it. **ctx** is your DataContext. This works for me :-)

Comment: This example uses LINQ to SQL while the question was about Entity Framework.