# Related Entities won't load for one particular entity

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've got a `Payment`, which has a `UserAccountId` on it, which references a table called `User_Account`. I want to load the related `User_Account` with my query. It's always coming back `null`, even if I explicitly call `.Include("User_Account")`. Additionally, other related fields are not loading for `Payment`, even if I explicitly include them.

If I look at other Entities, their related entities are loaded without explicitly asking for them. If I do `ctx.User_Account.ToList()`, the (there's only one) `User_Account` has a list of `Payments` (of just one -- the one I'm looking for).

The `UserAccountId` is a foreign key in the DB, and it is populated on the entity I'm looking at. Here's my code:

```
var payments = (from p in ctx.Payments.Include("User_Account")
                join pi in ctx.PaymentInvoices on p.Id equals pi.PaymentId
                where (p.UserId == userId || userId == -99) &&
                      (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParams.DocumentNumber) || p.TransactionID == searchParams.DocumentNumber) &&
                      (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParams.PONumber) || pi.PONumber == searchParams.PONumber) &&
                      (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchParams.SelectedStatus) || p.Status == searchParams.SelectedStatus) &&
                      (searchParams.SelectedBillTos.Contains(pi.CustomerId))
                select p).Distinct();
return payments.ToList();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761104/how-does-linq-expression-syntax-work-with-include-for-eager-loading try that!

Comment: Hmm, that seems to suggest putting the `.Include` after the query, but it seems EF 4.0 doesn't have a definition for `.Include` on an `IQueryable<T>`, only on `ObjectQuery<T>`...