# C# LINQ to Entities - Select specified Data from two tables, populate existing Model Classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a database and am using C# LINQ to Entities using Query Syntax.

Each DB table has it's own Entity Framework generated model class, the DB tables and model classes are named `Release` and `Version` *(there are others but this is my immediate problem)*.

I'm trying to load specific data into these model classes based on a query.

Essentially I want every `Release` column & row, along with its associated `Version` records populated in the Navigation Property `Release.Versions`.

However, two crucial points here:

**1) I only want certain 'Version' properties to be populated from the Query**
*(I only need some of the data for use in an Overview page - I can't see the point of dragging back all the data (which could be quite sizeable) if I am not using it).*

**2) I want the query to populate the already existing Model classes of Release and Version.**
*(Release.Versions Navigation property being populated with the Version records with cherry picked data from point 1 above)*

All this I could do in a long winded way with Stored Procedures - no issue, but thought EF Linq would be quicker. Ha. Ha. Haaaa.

So:

```
Release.ID            <---- Primary Key
Release.Col_1         <---- Other Properties (or columns)
Release.Col_2
Release.Col_3
Release.Versions      <---- Navigation Property to collection of Version records for each Release.

Version.ID            <---- Primary Key
Version.Release_ID    <---- Foreign Key to Release Table
Version.Col_1         <---- Many properties, just want first 4 properties obtained from DB.
Version.Col_2
Version.Col_3
Version.Col_4
Version.Col_5
Version.Col_x...
```

I just can't get the syntax right.

This is what I have (I've tried many other variants but nothing as simple as I remember it being):

```
var query = (from r in context.Releases
             join v in context.Versions on r.ID equals v.Release_ID
             select r).ToList();

returnedRecords= new ObservableCollection<Model.Release>(query);
```

I seem to remember having to use the `select new Release { x,y,z }` and then a nested `new Version { x, y, z}` - but cannot for the life of me remember how to do it, or how to get it to populate the Navigation property `Versions` within the `Release` class.

Maybe using Lambda syntax???????

**EDIT:**

OK, it appears I cannot do what I thought I could do.
So, I'm not going to use Query Syntax as most of the tutorials and documentation I can find are in Method Syntax. Plus I think Include only works with Method syntax, so seems a bit pointless using Query Syntax.

Answer marked as correct is how I loaded the Navigation Properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does LINQ expression syntax work with Include() for eager loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761104/how-does-linq-expression-syntax-work-with-include-for-eager-loading)

Comment: Doesn't `Release` have a navigation property `Versions`?

Comment: Gert Arnold >> Yes, but it's not populated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply load 'foreign' records for your table by using Include method.

```
var x = context.Releases.Include("Versions").ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the query to return the model class Release with a nested Version class, you can do it like this:

```
var query = (from r in context.Releases

             join v in context.Versions on r.ID equals v.Release_ID

             select new Release 
                        { 
                            releaseColumn1 = r.releaseColumn1, 
                            releaseColumn12 = r.releaseColumn2,
                            releaseVersion = new Version
                                                {
                                                    versionColumn1 = v.versionColumn1,
                                                    versionColumn2 = v.versionColumn2
                                                }
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: No. You can't new up entity objects in an EF query.

Comment: @GertArnold From what I understand from the question, the "model class Release" is a DTO and not a entity object. DTO can be created like the way I did in my answer.