# LINQ syntax : how to have the same purpose?

Tags: c#, linq

SQL queries generated by LINQ with `query` syntax are better compared to `method` syntax, but how do you achieve the same end?

`method` syntax:

```
var query = __repository.GetContext().Set<ObjectModel>()
                                .Include(obj => obj.ObjectTypeObjectAttributes)
                                .ThenInclude(otoa => otoa.TypeObjectAttribute)
                                .ThenInclude(toa => toa.Attribute);
```

`query` syntax:

```
var query = from obj in _repository.GetContext().Set<ObjectModel>()
                    join otoa in _repository.GetContext().Set<ObjectTypeObjectAttributeModel>() on obj.Id equals otoa.ObjectId
                    join toa in _repository.GetContext().Set<TypeObjectAttributeModel>() on otoa.TypeObjectAttributeId equals toa.Id
                    join att in _repository.GetContext().Set<AttributeModel>() on toa.AttributeId equals att.Id
                    orderby toa.Attribute.Name ascending
                    select new { obj, otoa, toa, att };
```

The use of the `method` syntax creates instances of `ObjectModel` with the navigation property of the `ObjectTypeObjectAttributeModel` type, which is not the case with the `query` syntax. Is it possible to have the same result with the `query` syntax?

I focused on the `query` syntax because it is possible to perform an `orderby` clause on a property of `ObjectTypeObjectAttributes` which is of type collection, which is not possible with the `method` syntax in ef core 3.x.

SQL generated with `method` syntax:

```
    SELECT [o].[Id], [o].[TypeObjectId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[AttributeValue], [t0].[ObjectId], [t0].[TypeObjectAttributeId], [t0].[Id0], [t0].[AttributeId], [t0].[TypeObjectId], [t0].[Unicity], [t0].[Id1], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Type]
FROM [ru].[Object] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [o0].[Id], [o0].[AttributeValue], [o0].[ObjectId], [o0].[TypeObjectAttributeId], [t].[Id] AS [Id0], [t].[AttributeId], [t].[TypeObjectId], [t].[Unicity], [a].[Id] AS [Id1], [a].[Description], [a].[Name], [a].[Type]
    FROM [ru].[ObjectTypeObjectAttribute] AS [o0]
    INNER JOIN [ru].[TypeObjectAttribute] AS [t] ON [o0].[TypeObjectAttributeId] = [t].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [ru].[Attribute] AS [a] ON [t].[AttributeId] = [a].[Id]
) AS [t0] ON [o].[Id] = [t0].[ObjectId]
ORDER BY [o].[Id], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Id0], [t0].[Id1]
```

SQL generated with `query` syntax:

```
    SELECT [o].[Id], [o].[TypeObjectId], [o0].[Id], [o0].[AttributeValue], [o0].[ObjectId], [o0].[TypeObjectAttributeId], [t].[Id], [t].[AttributeId], [t].[TypeObjectId], [t].[Unicity], [a].[Id], [a].[Description], [a].[Name], [a].[Type]
FROM [ru].[Object] AS [o]
INNER JOIN [ru].[ObjectTypeObjectAttribute] AS [o0] ON [o].[Id] = [o0].[ObjectId]
INNER JOIN [ru].[TypeObjectAttribute] AS [t] ON [o0].[TypeObjectAttributeId] = [t].[Id]
INNER JOIN [ru].[Attribute] AS [a] ON [t].[AttributeId] = [a].[Id]
INNER JOIN [ru].[Attribute] AS [a0] ON [t].[AttributeId] = [a0].[Id]
ORDER BY [a0].[Name]
```

Comment: `SQL queries generated by LINQ with query syntax are better compared to method syntax, but how do you achieve the same end?` Says who?

Comment: Last paragraph also only speaks of method syntax. It's a bit confusing, which is working as desired and which one not.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/6776439/34092 work?

Comment: [Don't signal your edits in text.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text)

Comment: @mjwills stackoverflow.com/a/6776439/34092 no, that's bad. ef core wraps the SQL query in a `FROM` clause and performs a new join.

Comment: @WDKyle Queries that can look "bad" often perform fine by the database since it will treat various forms of a query the same way. So the first question is **did it work?** Then the second question is **what performance analysis did you do on it to compare it to your existing options?**

Answer (score 1):

### Your queries are really very different!

Your method syntax will return all ObjectModels, each with their zero or more ObjectTypeAttributes.

Your query syntax will return for every ObjectTypeObjetAttribute its one and only ObjectModel.

So if you have:

- ObjectModel [10] has ObjectTypeAttributes [20], [21], [22],
- ObjectModel [11] has ObjectTypeAttribute [23]
- ObjectModel [12] has no ObjectTypeAttributes,

then your method syntax will return a sequence of three items, similar to the above. This is because it uses a GroupJoin, which is similar to a left outer join followed by a GroupBy.

Your query syntax will return a sequence of four items, similar to the one below:

- ObjectModel [10] - ObjectTypeAttribute [20]
- ObjectModel [10] - ObjectTypeAttribute [21]
- ObjectModel [10] - ObjectTypeAttribute [22]
- ObjectModel [11] - ObjectTypeAttribute [23]

This is because you did an inner join. Appart from that the data of ObjectModel [10] is transferred several times, you'll miss ObjectModel [12].

### Back to your question

If you want an inner join in method syntax, similar to your query syntax:

```
var result = dbContext.ObjectModels.Join(
    dbContext.ObjectTypeAttributes,

    // join on the following keys:
    objectModel => objectModel.Id,                       // from every ObjectModel take the primary key in Id
    objectTypeAttribute => objectTypeAttribute.ObjectId, // from every ObjectTypeAttribute take the foreign key in ObjectId

    // parameter resultSelector
    // for every objectModel and a matching typeAttribute make one new
    (objectModel, objectTypeAttribute) => new
    {
        // In your query: select the complete ObjectModel:
        ObjectModel = objectModel,
        TypeAttribute = objectTypeAttribute,

        // Or if you want, select only the properties that you plan to use:
        ObjectModel = new
        {
            Id = objectModel.Id,
            Name = objectModel.Name,
            ...
       }

       TypeAttribute = new
       {
           Id = objectTypeAttribute.Id,
           Name = objectTypeAttribute.Name,

           // Not needed: the foreign key, you already know the value!
           // ObjectId = objectTypeAttribute.ObjectId
       });
```

So there is some room for improvement: apart from that you transfer the same ObjectModel [10] several times, you also send the foreign key in the ObjectTypeAttribute several times, while you already know the value.

Consider whether a GroupJoin wouldn't be more suitable for your problem.

Comment: i agree that the generated SQL queries are not the same but that's another story. My real concern is to know if we can in absolute terms if both methods generate the same SQL query, how to get a list of `ObjectModel` with its navigation properties using the `query` syntax ?

Comment: Why do you want to use the query syntax @WDKyle?